# Why isn't my final JOptionPane message showing up?

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String colour = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What's your favourite colour?");
        int shade = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("From a scale of 1-10, 10 being the darkest and 1 being the lightest, what shade do you like?"));
        String response = "";

        if (colour == "Red") { 
            if (shade < 5)
                response = "Light Red";
                else 
                    response = "Dark Red";
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your colour is " + response);
        }
    }
}
```

Why doesn't the final JOptionPane message show up? For example, the user enters "Red" and then "1", the response isn't showing up as "Light Red".

Comment: because the whole `if` block is not executing since `colour` is not the same **instance** as `"Red"` - try using `if (colour.equals("Red")) {` https://stackoverflow.com/q/513832/85421 ; and maybe you should move the `JOptionPane` line one line down, outside the `if` block to also get an output if user did not enter "Red" (setting a default `response`)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger I've included your second suggestion in my answer, hope that's alright.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

The most likely explanation is that your code flow is never entering the parent `if` block that shows the message dialogue. As the comment on your question stated, this is most likely due to the fact that you are comparing two string using `==` operator instead of the `equals(String)` method. Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10806192/5759072) for more information about the difference between these two ways of comparing strings.

This is the short summary of the answer linked above:

> The equals() method compares the "value" inside String instances (on the heap) irrespective if the two object references refer to the same String instance or not.
>
> The "==" operator compares the value of two object references to see whether they refer to the same String instance.

This is how your code should look like:

```
String response = "Unknown";

if (colour.equals("Red")) {
    response = shade < 5 ? "Light Red" : "Dark Red";
}
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your colour is " + response);
```

Note that I've taken some liberties in shortening down the assignment of new value to the `response` field (as this should make it a more compact and readable) and moved the `showMessageDialog` method outside the `if` block (as @CarlosHeuberger suggested) so that it provides a message even when the color the user has selected is not red.

Comment: Thanks for the help and extra info, really appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome and since you are new to Stack Overflow I would recommend reading [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Accepting an answer is not meant to be a definitive and final statement indicating that your question has now been answered perfectly. It simply means that you received an answer that worked for you personally. Also read [What does it mean when answer is accepted?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).